# How to integrate myether wallet in ICO crowd-sale application with python web3.py library

Tags: myetherwallet, ico, web3.py

I am new to ethereum block-chain. I am learning to implantation of **Ethereum decentralise application** with **python web3.py**. I successfully compile and deploy smart contract with **web3.py**.

Now, I want to create a functionality in which user click on **buy token** button,on click of buy token button **MyEther**wallet is open. And end user will complete his transaction.

I used **matamask** wallet for same case. But in this case I used **web3.js library**. I do not want to use **matamask** plugin with python **web3.py** because it is run on browser. And browser support java-script language. So, my query is:-

How I integrate MyEther wallet in ICO crowd-sale application with python web3.py??

Comment: Can you explain more why you don't want to use web3.js? If you are trying to integrate with the browser, web3.py is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I already worked with web3.js and metamask walet.  Now I want to work with web3.py. In that case how I integrate myether wallet in Dapps application with web3.py??

Comment: And I know metamask wallet is browser friendly. So in python web3.py which ethereum wallet we can use.

Comment: In web3.py, you can either use the account in the node that you're connected to, or you can manage the private keys locally: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html

Comment: So, I don't need any wallet . But I want to provide wallet interface where user insert his password with web3.py python .And his wallet address is created. He import  his account address and connect to network(rinkeby, ropsten) .